# MySQL - How to create an auto increement field in the DB?

Tags: mysql

I am entering records in the MySQL DB. Now I want to have a "Serial_Number" field that increements automatically whenever a record is entered into the DB.

I don't want this "Serial_Number" field to be the primary key of the DB.

How can I create this field (with the attributes needed to be set).

I am using "SQL YOG" to access MySQL. If you are aware of the SQL YOG then tell me how to do that through SQL YOG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column has to have a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint associated to it.

For instance, this will work just fine:

```
CREATE TABLE AutoNotId
(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Auto INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UNIQUE (Auto)
);
```

**Edit:**

The `ALTER` statement would look somewhat like this:

```
ALTER TABLE AutoNotId
    MODIFY COLUMN Auto INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD UNIQUE (Auto);
```

I recommended, however the use of the long-hand syntax to specify the name of the `UNIQUE` constraint; But you can always refer to [MySQL's Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html) for the exact specifications.

Comment: Thanks Zxpro... you query works fine.
Can you tell me the alter command to alter my existing "sr_no" field in the "orkut" table to set this field to be auto_increment and unique.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL tables can only have one auto increment field and they must be indexed.

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT  column per table, it must be indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value.

Is there a reason you don't want it to be the primary key?

If you want an incrementing value, you could fudge it by running updates after each insert:

```
SELECT MAX(serial) + 1 FROM myTable;

UPDATE myTable SET serial = <that number> WHERE id = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have an auto increment field:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (`dd` int(11) NOT NULL) 
ALTER TABLE `t` CHANGE `dd` `dd` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

MySQL said: Documentation
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Comment: Can you suggest me how can I do this by any other alternative. I am saving the records through java through JDBC driver.

Comment: people have already pointed out that you can use a unique index. this is okay since it's not a primary key.

(how you access the database is not relevant to your issue).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in MySQL. From the doc:

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column per table, **it must be indexed**,
>   and it cannot have a DEFAULT value. An
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column works properly
>   only if it contains only positive
>   values. Inserting a negative number is
>   regarded as inserting a very large
>   positive number. This is done to avoid
>   precision problems when numbers “wrap”
>   over from positive to negative and
>   also to ensure that you do not
>   accidentally get an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column that contains 0.
>
> For MyISAM and BDB tables, **you can
>   specify an AUTO_INCREMENT secondary
>   column in a multiple-column key**. See
>   Section 3.6.9, “Using AUTO_INCREMENT”.

Answer (score -3):

create table mytable (
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,

SN INT IDENTITY(1,1)

)

Comment: This is not a MySQL statement.